# Anonymous labels in AT&T assembly

Tags: assembly, att

Is there a way to jump to the next/previous label in AT&T assembly without encumbering the namespace, like `jmp @f` [in the Intel syntax](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/FASM_Syntax#Anonymous_Labels)?

Comment: Yes, called "local labels": https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html#Local-Labels-1

Comment: @rkhb thanks! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Done. It was a little bit difficult to puff up the link only comment :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is called "local labels" and is even more powerful than the MASM/FASM variant:

https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html#Local-Labels-1

The label consists of only one number. The forward or backward jump is specified with this number.

Example (Labels 2 and 3 inside `m_newline` and `jne 1b` pretty near the end):

```
.macro m_newline
    jmp 3f                      # Skip over data
    2: .ascii "\n\0"            # Local label
    3:                          # Local label
    mov $2b,%ecx                # Pointer to the string "\n"
    mov $1,%edx                 # strlen = 1 byte to write
    mov $1,%ebx                 # STDOUT
    mov $4,%eax                 # WRITE
    int $0x80                   # Call kernel
.endm

.macro m_strlen                 # ESI = Pointer to zero terminated string
    mov %esi, %edi              # ES:EDI for scasb
    mov $-1, %ecx               # ECX = max
    xor %al, %al                # Search for zero
    repnz scasb
    mov %edi, %edx
    sub %esi, %edx
    dec %edx                    # EDX = strlen
    mov %esi, %ecx              # ECX = Pointer to the string
.endm

.macro m_puts
    m_strlen                    # ESI -> EDX and ECX
    mov $1,%ebx                 # STDOUT
    mov $4,%eax                 # WRITE
    int $0x80                   # Call kernel
    m_newline                   # Write new line
.endm

.text
_start:

    xor %eax, %eax

    1:
    mov 4(%esp,%eax,4),%esi     # mov esi, [esp + eax * 4 + 4]

    push %eax
    m_puts
    pop %eax

    inc %eax
    cmp (%esp), %eax
    jne 1b                      # backwards to the previous label "1"

    mov (%esp),%ebx             # Exitcode
    mov $1,%eax                 # EXIT
    int $0x80                   # Call kernel
```

Comment: A branch inside a macro expanded multiple times is a good example use-case for a local label.  That would Just Work.